# Send Request and parse the response json retrofit2

Tags: android, retrofit2

i am building my first intro app,  i have a doubt,  is it possible to send a request to server and get the response as a json and parse it,  if so how do i achieve it using retrofit2 in android.  But if retrofit is not the right thing for it then what do i use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://square.github.io/retrofit/ this might help

Comment: you can go with retrofit2 in your app....

Comment: Thank you Riten and Sakchham!